# Compress List to find common string, assign code and return itemised results in separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and just trying to build a very basic tool but I am a little stuck so hoping someone can help!

I have setup as in the image below
[image: Data]

I'd like to take the string in column B and compress it so that at the click of a button (pre-created) I create a list which contains only the string that varies i.e. Apple, Apple 1, Banana and Banana 2. This list needs to present in the Codes tab where the user can assign an integer to each (1 and 2).

Once the codes are assigned the user would click the button and the codes would appear in a third tab (Results) with the itemised number and code next to it.

I hope this makes sense. I'm really not sure where to start with this!

Thanks in advance!

I've attempted various things I've found on the internet to compress the list but couldn't get the code to compile.

Please see screenshots of how the tabs will be set out below:
[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKcIe.png)

[Coding Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l04Gb.png)

[Results Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krp7e.png)

Comment: This could be a nice usecase for a very simple userform if you wish for this kind of interaction with your users. A dictionary will get you started with builing unique key's that can even hold values you (your users) would assign to them.

Comment: Why don't you share the screenshots of all the worksheets and add the code you have already written? BTW, you wrote `Banana 1`: didn't you mean `Banana 2`?

Comment: I have a dictionary of string and codes as a starting point for the the code to theoretically search once I've got it up and running. But as I said I have no idea where to begin.

Unfortunately a userform wouldn't work as the data is something we receive and manage not create.

Yes I did mean Banana 2, I have amended it in the q.

Comment: What about the screenshots? I'm guessing the `Codes` tab, the 1st tab, is shown in the posted screenshot. What about the `Results` tab, and most importantly, what about the 2nd tab, since you claim that `Results` is the 3rd tab? In a nutshell, show us what the results should look like.

Comment: I've added the screenshots in. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, now we have something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

### Dealing With Unique Values Using a Dictionary

**A *Very Basic Tool*(s)**

- It is assumed that each numbered item has a base item.

```vb
Sub WriteCoding()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write from source range to source array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sws.Range("B2", _
        sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    ' Write unique from source array to dictionary.
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim drID As Long
    Dim CurrId As Long
    Dim SpacePosition As Long
    Dim cString As String
    Dim BaseString As String
        
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        cString = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If Not sDict.Exists(cString) Then
            If Right(cString, 1) Like "#" Then
                SpacePosition = InStrRev(cString, " ")
                BaseString = Left(cString, SpacePosition - 1)
                If sDict.Exists(BaseString) Then
                    CurrId = sDict(BaseString)
                Else
                    drID = drID + 1
                    CurrId = drID
                    sDict(BaseString) = CurrId
                End If
            Else
                drID = drID + 1
                CurrId = drID
            End If
            sDict(cString) = CurrId
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Erase sData
    
    ' Write from dictionary to destination array.
    
    Dim dFirst As String: dFirst = CStr(sws.Range("B1").Value)
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = sDict.Count
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 3)
    
    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For Each sKey In sDict.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        dData(dr, 1) = dFirst
        dData(dr, 2) = sKey
        dData(dr, 3) = sDict(sKey)
    Next sKey
    
    Set sDict = Nothing
    
    ' Write from destination array to destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Coding")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A2").Resize(drCount, 3)
    
    drg.Value = dData

End Sub


Sub WriteResults()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Lookup
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets("Coding")
    Dim lData() As Variant: lData = lws.Range("B2", _
        lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2).Value
    
    rCount = UBound(lData, 1)
    
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        lDict(lData(r, 1)) = lData(r, 2)
    Next r
    
    Erase lData
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A2", slCell)
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Offset(, 1).Value
    
    rCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = srg.Value
    ReDim Preserve dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
        
    ' Loop
        
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If lDict.Exists(sData(r, 1)) Then
            dData(r, 2) = lDict(sData(r, 1))
        End If
    Next r
    
    Set lDict = Nothing
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Results")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A2").Resize(rCount, 2)
    
    drg.Value = dData

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! I'm going to try and unpick it so I can learn from it :)

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of items and a code table, this code will extract the code based on the common element (assuming it's the first word of the item description, eg Apples 1 -> Apples, Apples 2 -> Apples)

```
Option Compare Text
Sub CategorizeItems(inputArray As Variant, codeRange As Variant, Optional outputRange As Range)
'example use
'CategorizeItems activesheet.listobjects("Table3").databodyrange.value,activesheet.listobjects("Table1").databodyrange.value,[J2]
'
'example output
'  |1   |2      |3       |4
'1 |Item|Name   |Category|Index
'2 |1   |Apple  |Apple   |1
'3 |2   |banana |banana  |2
'4 |3   |apple  |apple   |1
'5 |4   |apple  |apple   |1
'6 |5   |Apple  |Apple   |1
'7 |6   |banana |banana  |2
'8 |7   |Apple 1|Apple   |1
'9 |8   |banana |banana  |2
'10|9   |Apple  |Apple   |1
'11|10  |Apple 1|Apple   |1

    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim found As String: found = "|"
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 1
    Dim item As String
    Dim var
    ReDim var(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
    var(1, 1) = "Item"
    var(2, 1) = "Name"
    var(3, 1) = "Category"
    var(4, 1) = "Index"
    ReDim Preserve var(1 To 4, 1 To UBound(var, 2) + 1)
    
    Dim index As Long
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In inputArray
        item = Split(element, " ")(0)
        index = WorksheetFunction.index(var, WorksheetFunction.Match("apple", WorksheetFunction.index(var, 1), 0), 2)
'--------If argument was range
'        index = codeRange.Columns(1).Find(item).OFFSET(0, 1).Value
'--------If instead of finding existing codes you want to ASSIGN unique codes as you find new items:
'        If InStr(1, found, "|" & item & "|", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'            found = found & item & "|"
'            index = coll.count + 1
'        Else:index = coll(item)
'        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        coll.Add index, item
        On Error GoTo 0
        var(1, UBound(var, 2)) = UBound(var, 2) - 1
        var(2, UBound(var, 2)) = element
        var(3, UBound(var, 2)) = item
        var(4, UBound(var, 2)) = index
        ReDim Preserve var(1 To 4, 1 To UBound(var, 2) + 1)
    Next
    var = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(var)
    If Not outputRange Is Nothing Then outputRange.RESIZE(UBound(var, 1), UBound(var, 2)).Value = var
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can also be used to generate the categories and indexes

Comment: Unfortunately it is not always the first word which I need to compare... is it possible to adjust the above to look for the full string?

Comment: If I wanted to add another column of variables so say the colour of the fruit could that also be coded in?

Comment: yes, you can add more columns (as in var(5,ubound(var,2))=...). You can also look for full string, for example by using item=element.